# Android test project Manifest: how to automatically edit instrumentation target package?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, testing, automated-tests

I'm trying to build a project that can be used to test any Android app (I'm currently using Eclipse, btw).

My problem is:
The Android test project must define the target package in the instrumentation tag in the Manifest file. However I want to be able to change the application I'm testing without manually editing the Manifest.

Can anyone help me? I hope I made it clear enough :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, what I can say is that it is not possible to do it from the test-project itself. It is necessary to do it from another application and then update the test-project.